# Get the contents of a td without an "id" attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML. How can I fetch the contents of the `TD` which is under `tr class="status_visible"` in JavaScript?. I have highlighted the `td` that I am interested in the code below. There could be multiple `status_visible` rows. I am only interested in the first row.

There is no `id`, so I can't use `getElementById()`. (I also can't use jQuery)

```html
<table class="colored">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9">
                <h2>History</h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Change Reason</th>
            <th>Changed By</th>
            <th>Changing Environment</th>
            <th>Change Date (UTC)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="status_visible">
            <td>N</td>   <!-- get this value -->
            <td>CSS-ID: 343423</td>
            <td>login_details</td>
            <td>applicationname::signedinuser</td>
            <td>2018-01-02 21:09:47 +0000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="status_hidden">
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>CSS-ID:5554</td>
            <td>ServiceName</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2014-02-19 13:37:50 +0000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which of the 5 `td`s do you want to get the contents of? Will there be more than one "status_visible" `tr`? If so, will you want values from all, or just the first?

Comment: (please clarify *in the question*, not in the comments)

Comment: i am just interested in `td` value of the first `tr`. I am going to highlight the `td` i am interest in original quesiton.

Comment: try something like document.querySelectorAll(".status_visible  td");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with this selector:

```
'tr.status_visible td:nth-child(n)'
```

… where `n` is the column of the `td` you're interested in (1-based).

For example, this will grab the text content of the first `td` of the `tr` having class "status_visible":

```
document.querySelector('tr.status_visible td:nth-child(1)').textContent
```

**Snippet:**

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('tr.status_visible td:nth-child(1)').textContent);
```

```html
<table class="colored">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">
        <h2>History</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Change Reason</th>
      <th>Changed By</th>
      <th>Changing Environment</th>
      <th>Change Date (UTC)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="status_visible">
      <td>N</td>
      <td>CSS-ID: 343423</td>
      <td>login_details</td>
      <td>applicationname::signedinuser</td>
      <td>2018-01-02 21:09:47 +0000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="status_hidden">
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>CSS-ID:5554</td>
      <td>ServiceName</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2014-02-19 13:37:50 +0000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the `td`'s and show the text content using `.textContent` like :

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('tr.status_visible td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  console.log(tds[i].textContent);
}
```

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('tr.status_visible td');

for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  console.log(tds[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<table class="colored">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">
        <h2>History</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Change Reason</th>
      <th>Changed By</th>
      <th>Changing Environment</th>
      <th>Change Date (UTC)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="status_visible">
      <td>N</td>
      <td>CSS-ID: 343423</td>
      <td>login_details</td>
      <td>applicationname::signedinuser</td>
      <td>2018-01-02 21:09:47 +0000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="status_hidden">
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>CSS-ID:5554</td>
      <td>ServiceName</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2014-02-19 13:37:50 +0000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```